# Can I hide my helm without buying dye?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've crafted my first Rare item. It came in the form of a **ridiculous looking helmet**.

I am aware there is an item called Vanishing Dye that will make whatever item dyed turn invisible. This would be useful in hiding my silly little hat, but I honestly don't feel the 300+ gold is worth spending just to hide my hat (or other clothing if I wanted to look like the world's strongest naked person).

**Is there anyway to show/hide helmets without buying dye/dye remover?**

Comment: Yeah, take it off. But seriously, 300 gold? What does that take, 20 seconds of gameplay to earn? Jump on the AH and get gold dye, it's going for 5k+... But looks awesome!

Comment: 300 gold is nothing.  This isn't WoW where there's silver and copper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't hide your helm without a dye. There was a [blue (official) post](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/2690979675#12) about them not planning on having that feature while the game was still in development.